# Laravel 4 - CSRF token never changes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, token, csrf

I am creating forms, and it does not matter how I do it, the CSRF _token is always the same!

It doesnt matter if I use

```
{{ Form::open([route' => 'login']) ]]
```

or if I use

```
{{ Form::token() }}
```

It is the same one every single time. **Even** after I make a successful Form submission. I figured it would get consumed and a new one would be generated, but no!

Did I miss a configuration step?

Note: I know that if the `laravel_session` gets regenerated, the _token is different, but as I had understand, the CRSF token was also the mechanism to avoid *multiple form submissions* , so it should change on every refresh of page, or at least after is consumed after one successful post submission, no?

Comment: Where have you read that `CRSF token was also the mechanism to avoid multiple form submissions`, please?

Comment: It was also discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239586/laravel-4-prevent-multiple-form-submissions-csrf-token

Comment: While that post does explain a method to avoid form resubmission, it does not explain the behavior about the token not being consumed. I would like to crack this, because it seems like a security hole.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not necessary to refresh the CSRF token for every request, generating the token per session will also be safe. Have a look at the [Owasp cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) for a better explanation.

Regenerating the token for every request can be done, but can result in usability issues. I think this is the reason why Laravel implements the token per session approach.

Comment: Thank you, that is quite an exhaustive explanation. It seems in the end this is the expected behavior.

Comment: If I log out and log back in, does that count as a session change? I mean if I log out and log back in, will the token change?

Comment: @Rohan - Actually it depends on what the application will do when the user logs out. Technically a session cookie could remain valid until the browser is closed, though often the session is discarded when the user logs out.

Answer (score 2):

From the code, the only relevant occurrences of `_token` or `regenerateToken` are in the [Illuminate/Session/Store](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php), lines 89, 551 and 571. The occurences being:

```
public function start()
{
    $this->loadSession();

    if ( ! $this->has('_token')) $this->regenerateToken();

    return $this->started = true;
}

public function token()
{
    return $this->get('_token');
}

public function regenerateToken()
{
    $this->put('_token', str_random(40));
}
```

This means, that token gets only regenerated, when not present in Sessions. You have to regenerate it yourself if you want, with i.e. `Session::forget('_token');`