# Laravel 4 - Preventing form from submitting multiple entries

Tags: php, forms, laravel, submit

I'm having a problem when I submit forms with POST requests, if I "spam" (click the submit button as many times as I can before the page redirects) the submit button it creates a request for each time I press the button. Why is it doing this? Is it because the CSRF token isn't regenerating? Is it because im running on localhost, I really have no clue what the hell is happening and I'm starting to lose it.

So what's happening is that for every click to the submit button on the form it inserts that many entries of duplicate data.

I've searched and found one other post here on Stack with the same problem as me.

[Prevent creating multiple entries with Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974672/prevent-creating-multiple-entries-with-laravel-4)

But the answer doesn't really satisfy me.. There must be a better way to go about this and apply on all post requests.

*EDIT*
Here's a link to my controller containing the beforeFilter, my resource controllers and the view.

Comment: please define spam in your question.  you might reference http://laravel.com/docs/security

Comment: @PaulBastide Yeah, that might have been a little vague, I went ahead and edited it now.. There's nothing about my problem in there tho.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF doesn't prevent the request from being made.  It only prevents the request from being processed.  If (in chrome), you open your developer tools and check the network tab, only the first request appears in black before the redirect is made (the rest are red which indicates an error.)

If you would like to disable requests after the 1st from being made before the page reloads, you could disable the submit button with jQuery or Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#your-submit-button-id').click(function(){
        $('#your-submit-button-id').attr('disabled', true);
    });

});
```

Comment: Yeah okay, I get that. But, why does it go through even if gets cancelled? I'd like to think that something that is cancelled gets negated. Also I'd rather not do anything with JS if possible since it can be turned off and then the stuff would go through anyway..

Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Each request made from a client to a server gets some sort of response.  In the event of posting with an invalid token (second, third, etc.... requests), this is a 302 (redirect) by default,  which is caught in your `before` filter before it ever hits your route.  Unfortunately, this requires a server request, and is as close as you can get without implementing some sort of client-side solution, which usually means jQuery or JavaScript.  Why are you concerned with the additional requests?  That is what CSRF is intended for.

Comment: Because in my case the additional requests are making a new entry in my database. For example if i go to my create form and type in some stuff and then hit submit 6 times before the next page loads then it also puts 6 duplicate entries.

Comment: Ah, ok, then that means that CSRF is not working properly.  Can you post your routes, CSRF filter, and the form's view?

Comment: HHmmmm everything looks ok to me, assuming you have the default `csrf` filter in `app/filters.php`,  and the `access` filter isn't doing anything weird.  Setting the filter in your controller _should_ work, but i might suggest just using one generic route method so you don't have to set this in every controller.  Most people want CSRF on every  `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`.  At the top of your  `routes.php`.... `Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post', 'put', 'delete'));`

Comment: I tried doing like you said but it doesn't work either, I cant understand why its doing this.. I've got the default filter and the access filter is just something that checks if the account has access to the page.. Thanks for trying to help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

CSFR (Cross Site Request Forgery) is not for validating the number of requests but the SESSION. The token should regenerate after you clear cookies and cache in your browser.

If you want to prevent multiple requests from being submitted, disable the submit button as you mentioned above, or use a flag: https://jeykeu.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/jquery-prevent-multiple-ajax-requests/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding the following function: `"this.disabled=true;this.value='Submiting...';this.form.submit();"` 
 to the button's 'onclick' event will handle it.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Submiting...';this.form.submit();" class="btn">Submiting...</button>
```

Comment: What is "this"? Can you explain your solution, such that others can learn from it?

Comment: You're right, my answer is vague. I edited and case is still vague feel free to suggest a new edition.